# Dynamically swap css in react

Tags: css, reactjs, themes

Im generating two css files from my sass files with defined color variables
Lets call them `dark.css` and `light.css`
Now what i want to do is dynamically swap these two css to change themes

So far I have something like this

```
...
  componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.props.colorScheme === 'dark') {
        require('../../../static/css/style-dark.css');
      } else {
        require('../../../static/css/style-light.css');
      }
    }
  }
...
```

Above doesnt really work.Well it wroks ..partially

The problem is that theme is switched only once e.g default one is `light` then it can be changed to `dark` but after that no matter what i cant change it back to `light`

Had somebady similar problem? maybe this isnt a right way at all so any ideas are apprecited

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yeah, did you solve it?

Comment: @TransitoryMatt Its some time ago but i very blurry remember that I ended up with something like combining them into one stylesheet e.g `.light{ .myClass{//someCss} } .dark{.myClass{//some other css}}` and then just dynamically changing top level html tag like 
document.getElementbyId('root').removeClass("light")
document.getElementbyId('root').appendClass("dark")

It worked but be aware that this has some negative performance impacts. My project was backoffice app so that didnt really matter. If you intend to use it to public facing webpage try to come up with different solution

Comment: Yeah this is what we currently do and it works very well without page refresh - but as we are being forced to use an external design system (which isn't adequately name-spaced) then we have to resort to reloading the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like that...

Create a js styles file instead of css styles file.

example **file1.js**

```
export default = ({
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  color: 'blue',
  paddingTop: 20,
  paddingBottom: 20,
});
```

```js
// file 1
//export default({  <-- replace this line in your file
const file1 = {
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  color: 'blue',
  paddingTop: 20,
  paddingBottom: 20,
};

// file 2
//export default({  <-- replace this line in your file
const file2 = {
  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  color: 'black',
  paddingTop: 40,
  paddingBottom: 40,
};

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      theme: 1,
      styles: {...file1},
    };
  }
  
  changeTheme = () => {
    this.setState({
      styles: this.state.theme === 1 ? {...file2} : {...file1},
      theme: this.state.theme === 1 ? 2 : 1,
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.state.styles}>
        Hello
        <button onClick={this.changeTheme}>
          Change Theme
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dashboard />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is i cannot import it from js file. Themes are generated from sass variables into css files.